# Google Play API development

Tags: android-development

I have a simple product consisting of 3 apps - Android mobile app in Google Play, backend API and backend administration website.

The API is connected to various external services but this question is specifically about Google Play's (GP) in-app billing system with [in-app products](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/inappproducts). My API can manage the GP's in-app products (using the admin website).

So far for easy development I've had production secrets in my GIT repository (for GP in-app products it is the GCP service JSON key connected to the GP app). This hasn't been a problem because I've been a sole developer in my company and noone else has access to the repository.

But I'm planning to hire some help in form of contractors so I'm going to migrate my production secrets and create new GIT repo for development without any secrets in history (and the GIT history of my development is not important so it can be forgotten).

For most of the secrets to external services there are easy solutions:

- The contractors will use their own accounts
- There is pre-made account for development purposes where no harm can be made

But I'm not sure how to handle Google Play secrets for the in-app products management.

- *The contractors will use their own accounts* -- this does not seem...right? Because you have to publish your own App, manage your own App ID for development, set up your own GCP. Setting up the whole GP environment was a huge pain in the ass for me.
- *There is pre-made account for development purposes where no harm can be made* - this means I'll setup another application in my GP just for development purposes (with different App ID) which the contractors can use directly. This feels more right?

Is it normal to create a different application in GP just for development purposes (an app that is never released/published)? What is the development approach when working with GP APIs (in-app products) and its secrets?

Comment: Asking if something is "normal" will attract opinion-based answers, which does not fit the Q&A format for this community. Is there a specific problem with having a "dev" account for your app?

Comment: Does Google give any recommendations?

Comment: Isn't soft. eng. stack exchange supposed to be subjective? Anyway, no, there is no official Google recommendation on this afaik

Comment: None of the stack exchange communities support purely subjective questions. One of the standard reasons for closing a question across the network is for being opinion-based. Questions in this community work best if the members can agree on a single comprehensive answer. Questions should focus on a single problem. Instead of asking what is "normal", can you [edit] your question to include a problem with your current solution?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68384/whats-the-difference-between-stack-overflow-and-software-engineering-se-previo -- "......who are interested in subjective discussions on software development."

I don't want to invest in discussing this further so this question can be closed/deleted if you want.

Comment: And that question predates a shift in the focus of this community. Since you are the question author, you can delete the question.